# Using showViewController with iOS Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, google-places-api, viewcontroller

So I'm building an app for the first time and I am using https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete. My code is down below.

```
func testFunction() {
    println(gpaViewController)

    let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! ViewController2
    self.showDetailViewController(view2, sender: self)
}
```

And in the extension ViewController I call the testFunction:

```
extension ViewController: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
    func placeSelected(place: Place) {
        println(place.description)

        place.getDetails { details in
            println(details)
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        println(self)
        testFunction()


    }

    func placeViewClosed() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to switch views after I click on the `tableView` cell. However, nothing happens. But when I attach the `testFunction` to `IBaction` and a button, it takes me to another `viewController`.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm trying to do something quite similar with the same library and haven't been able to find many "best practices" regarding something like this.